# Open Hyper as integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the following post https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27791 they mentioned hyper terminal cannot run as integrated terminal in VSCode because hyper self is hosted in electron.

They also mentioned that Hyper will implement xterm.
In the current canary version, xterm is implemented yet, see https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/1275

Does it mean that it is possible to run hyper as a integrated terminal in vscode?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to integrate hyper terminal with VSCode by adding the following to the settings.json

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe",
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27791#issuecomment-305547917

Refer this for your question before proceeding further

However, you can run it externally by pasting the snippet in settings.json in vs code.

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\hyper\\hyper.exe",
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)